# How to open a CV2.frame window from node-red? - Exec script to UI app

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi, node-red

I have an exec-node in node-red to execute 'lxterminal python3 code.py'. I want to run in foreground the script because I use cv2.imshow. Node-red just executes it at background so I can't see the camera output.

This node is the last one of a flow. I want to turn on a python script with opencv dependencies to detect objects and show the camera output in a screen.

Error message:

> (lxterminal:5169): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Thanks in advance

Node-red is autostarted at startup by user `pi`

Comment: Having an interactive step in the middle of the Node-RED flow like this doesn't make any sense. You need to update the question with exactly how you are starting Node-RED but it's most likely running as a service so has no access to the X Windows environment.

Comment: You have still not answered the question about HOW you are running/starting Node-RED.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that Node-RED is running as a service, which is started at boot time, as such it has no access to the X-Windows environment.

This is because while it is running as a service X-Windows might not be running, or there might not be a user logged on.

Running GUI code from Node-RED is really not what it's designed to do, even if it's the last node in the flow it will block that node indefinitely.

If you REALLY, REALLY need to do this (you REALLY, REALLY don't) then you should run the python code from a shell script that sets the `DISPLAY` environment variable first. Something like this:

```
#/bin/sh
export DISPLAY=:0.0
python foo.py
```

This will allow the python app to connect to X. but remember this will fail if the pi user is not logged in at the time.

Comment: I've tried but I couldn't afford anything. I think it's because I'm not a proper software developer, just an amateur guy doing stuff. Thanks for your time and effort  :-)